# Order elements of list according to predefined ordering

Tags: sorting

I have quite a lot of sublists of different length whose elements I would like to order according to a specific predefined ordering.

To be explicit: I am given a specific ordering of indices (i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,...) as well as sublists that can be of the form

{k,l},{l,i,k,m},{i,n,l},... .

I would now like to obtain e.g. a list that includes all the sublists with ordered indices, i.e. for the given case something like:

{{k,l},{i,k,l,m},{i,l,n},...}.

Edit: First, thank you for all the answers. In the previous post I have not expressed my issue properly, so let me elaborate further:

I really want to sort the "letters" (indices) and don't think of them as being replaced by numerical expressions as has been assumed by some of the answers. So the main idea is to associate the index list

(i,j,k,l,m,n,o) to (1,2,3,4,5,6,7), i.e.

(i->1,j->2,k->3,l->4,m->5,n->6,o->7),

such that a list that is formed by a some elements of the index set is sorted accordingly, e.g.

(m,k,i) (corresponding to (m->5,k->3,i->1))

would become

(i,k,m).

The question remains, what would be the best way to achieve this?

I am sorry to not have been clear before.
All the best.

Comment: If `alist = {{k, l}, {l, i, k, m}, {i, n, l}}` then `Sort /@ alist` would do this. Please load a concrete example, if this doesn't solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say we're given an ordering of the first 20 integers:

```
rawOrdering = {13, 15, 5, 14, 9, 8, 17, 20, 12, 1, 16, 4, 6, 10, 11, 18, 19, 2, 7, 3};
```

I assume that this is what you mean when you say you're given a specific ordering. So, according to this ordering, 13 is the min and 3 is the max.

We could use this to sort a list of integers (in the 1-20 range) by comparing their position in `rawOrdering`. But rather than search `rawOrdering` each time, we can map each integer to its index in `rawOrdering` and use that structure to sort. Here's the mapping:

```
indexOrdering = Ordering[rawOrdering]
```

`{10, 18, 20, 12, 3, 13, 19, 6, 5, 14, 15, 9, 1, 4, 2, 11, 7, 16, 17, 8}`

So, the position in `rawOrdering` of the integer 1 is found by just taking `indexOrdering[[1]]` (which is 10). In general, the position in `rawOrdering` of `n` is `indexOrdering[[n]]`. So, we have a function that can be used to sort.

To demonstrate, let's build a test list of sublists:

```
test = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18}, {19, 20}};
```

Let's sort each sublist by mapping Sort with an appropriate sorting function:

```
SortBy[indexOrdering[[#]] &] /@ test
```

`{{1, 4, 2, 3}, {5, 9, 8, 12, 6, 10, 11, 7}, {13, 15, 14}, {17, 16, 18}, {20, 19}}`

Caveat: This only works if the ordering you're given is complete for a given range (which I'm assuming it is because you referred to them as indices). If that condition isn't met, we can still do something similar but maybe not as simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
list = {i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q};

Sort /@ (Join @@ (Subsets[list, {#}] & /@ Range[Length[list]]))
```